Bottom Navigation not Working in React Native
I am new to react native and as part of my learning i decided to create a instagram clone.
The issue i am facing is that my bottomnavigator isnt wokring. I tried setting  tabBarPosition="bottom" and still didnt work.
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
import ProfilePage from '../screen/ProfilePage'
import ReelsPage from '../screen/ReelsPage'
import RecommendationsPage from '../screen/RecommendationsPage'
import { View, Image, Text } from "react-native"

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator tabBarPosition="bottom">
            <Tab.Screen name=" " component={RecommendationsPage}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/Images/home.png')} style={{
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                marginTop: "10%"
                            }} />
                        </View>
                    )
                }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="   " component={ReelsPage} options={{
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Image source={require('../../assets/Images/compass.png')} style={{
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                            marginTop: "10%"
                        }} />
                    </View>
                )
            }} />
            <Tab.Screen name="  " component={ProfilePage}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/Images/user.png')} style={{
                                height: 30,
                                width: 30,
                                marginTop: "10%"
                            }} />
                        </View>
                    )
                }} />
        </Tab.Navigator >
    )
}

export default BottomNavigation

this is the code of reference
solution to the above problem

If you provide some error stack or some images it would be more helpful. Anyway the logic seems correct but if you want to programmatically navigate between pages it's a good practice giving a name to your screens.
If you want to hide labels on the bottom bar use the tabBarLabel: "" option within your screen options.
This is a snack you can refer to see the implementation, as you can see the bottom bar is in the correct place:
https://snack.expo.dev/@giulio987/crabby-red-beef-jerky

Thank you for the reply. I later tried to fix it by using chat gpt. But it gave some more errors, Eventually i fixed it. Thank you for taking time to reply.

Can you share your solution as an answer @Joe?
